# Windows CMD equivalent of CTRL+X and CTRL+V

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd.exe

I know how to copy/move files in windows CMD. I use robocopy. But I want to move one directory from location A to location B immediately. Both locations are on same partition:

source: I:\actual
destination: I:\archive

I Want to move some dir from source to destination with all subfolders, files.... with all content. If I use robocopy it is realy copying files, which takes long, because it Is real copy all and then delete source - this requires enought free space.

I need efect same as if I use combination of CTRL+X and CTRL+V on explorer - not real copy, only changing records in folder list - this is immediately moving directory.

Is this possible some way??

Comment: are both locations on the same partition/filesystem? if not, no.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using `Move` command in command prompt?.

```
C:\> move c:\source   c:\destination
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible. You would use the `ren` resp. `rename` command. It's even described on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ren_%28command%29). If you want to copy a subdirectory `somedir` from `actual` to `archive, you would use this:

```
ren I:\actual\somedir I:\archive\somedir
```

Comment: Not like this. I need this:

I:\actual\somedir move to I:\archive\somedir

rename not works like this

Comment: Then use `ren I:\actual\somedir I:\archive\somedir` or just `ren I:\actual\somedir I:\archive`.